# Как обрабатывать несколько чатов/каналов с помощью Telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

Существует ли возможность обрабатывать несколько чатов/каналов с помощью одного события Newmessage в telethon?

Answer (score 2):

Для обработки сообщений с нескольких чатов/каналов просто в аргументе chats перечислите через запятую все необходимые чаты:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('chat1', 'chat2', 'chat3')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    print(event.message.to_dict()['message'])
```

Comment: Это не решило проблему, обрабатывается только первый чат, указанный в аргументе, остальные игнорируются

Comment: @Melkiywey, может быть у вас некорректное название/ссылка на чат? Взял из своего кода, у меня всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй айди канала или добавить @ перед названием канала. Также аккаунт нужно попробовать подписать на эти каналы